# Why x-axis E field exist in Electroosmosis Example

Tags: electrostatics, electrochemistry

[image]

The explanation in Wiki said it is because the surface charge will induce electrical double layer at top and bottom surface, so that if we apply x direction E field, there will be a flow between two walls.

My question is, why we can assume there is a x direction E field exist between the walls?

https://www.comsol.com/blogs/modeling-electroosmotic-flow-electrical-double-layer/

For example, in COMSOL simulation explanation they apply the electrode boundary at the both side of the tube.

But apparently we can see the Ex field is not constant in this potential result.
Most of potential will drop at the double layer. Why we can still get this ideal fluid flow by using this assumption?